# How to check whether key or value exist in Pyspark Map

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I have a Map column in a spark DF and would like to filter this column on a particular key (i.e. keep the row if the key in the map matches desired value).

For example, my schema is defined as:

```
df_schema = StructType(
  [StructField('id', StringType()),
   StructField('rank', MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))]
)
```

My sample data is:

```
{ "id": "0981850006", "rank": {"a": 1} }
```

Is there any way to filter my df on rows where "a" is in "rank" without using explode()?

Is there a better schema representation for the given json than what I have defined?

Comment: `explode` is probably the best solution. If you don't want to use it you will have to write a UDF

Comment: Thanks @Marie. Could you please suggest how I might write a UDF to do this, or provide guidance on accessing the key,value attributes of the Map type. I also attempted to access the Map key via sqlContext.sql("select rank.key from test_df"), but this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the key with `rank.key` would mean `rank` is a `StructType()`. Although explode is probably the best solution let's build a UDF to assess whether or not k is a key of `rank`.

First let's create our dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df_schema = StructType(
  [StructField('id', StringType()),
   StructField('rank', MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ["0981850006", {"a": 1}], 
    ["0981850006", {"b": 2, "c": 3}], 
], df_schema)
```

Now our UDF:

```py
def isKey(k,d):
    return k in d.keys()

isKey_udf = lambda k: psf.udf(lambda d: isKey(k,d), BooleanType())
```

Which gives:

```py
df.withColumn(
    "is_key", 
    isKey_udf('a')(df.rank)
)
    +----------+-------------------+------+
    |        id|               rank|is_key|
    +----------+-------------------+------+
    |0981850006|        Map(a -> 1)|  true|
    |0981850006|Map(b -> 2, c -> 3)| false|
    +----------+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: for beginners like me, psf is "pyspark.sql.functions"